# Remove Settings Access For Students

Tags: system-settings

Running Ubuntu 12 on a class set of netbooks and looking to block SETTINGS access to the standard user (student) Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: 12.10 or 12.04.2?

Comment: What do you mean by block SETTINGS access? In order to change most things users need to be part of the sudo group. All you need to do is make sure they are not a member of that group. Each computer will need at least one user who is a member of this group though but that doesn't need to be a student. See [RootSudo documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for details. Note by default first user is an administrator. Others are not unless specifically added

Answer (score 3):

Anything a logged-in user can do using the settings panel, s/he can do by editing files on the file system.

In a class situation, with many students logging in through one account, the better way is to reset the home directory of the *student* account after every logout.

Set up a template home directory and overwrite `/home/student` at the appropriate moment. Students will be free to change whatever setting they want for the duration of their session, but the next user will have an entirely standard environment again.

Oh and pick a seriously long password for the administrator user. ;-)